# How can we symbolically working out $\phi^4$ theory green's function/propagator and consequences in python?

Tags: python, pde, computational-physics, quantum-mechanics, multiphysics

I am having some difficulty calculating Green's function symbolically in Python for $\phi^4$ theory.

The specific rendition of the $\phi^4$ theory I have in mind can be written as follows.

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_t \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \frac{1}{4!} \lambda \phi^4$

$\phi$ is a function of $x$ and $t$

I have implemented Python code to give me the correct euler-lagrange equation.

Here it is

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy import diff
import math as math
from builtins import chr
from sympy import init_printing

init_printing(order='none')

x,t,m,k,y, eye = sp.symbols('x t m k y I')
kx,kt = sp.symbols('kx kt')
lbda = sp.Symbol(chr(955))
x_y = sp.Symbol('x-y')
phi = sp.Function(chr(0x03C6))(x,t)
dalembertian_symbol = sp.Symbol(chr(0x25A1))
integral_symbol = sp.Symbol(chr(8747))
kronecker_delta_symbol = sp.Symbol(chr(0x03B4))

xshift = x-y
tshift = t-y

D_x_y = sp.Symbol('D(x-y)')
D_k = sp.Symbol('D(k)')
D_x = sp.Symbol('D(x)')



L = 1/2 * ( phi.diff(t,1))**2 +  1/2 *( phi.diff(x,1) )**2  - 1/2 * m**2 * phi**2 -  (1/math.factorial(4)) * lbda * phi**4

phiDot =  phi.diff(t,1)
phix =  phi.diff(x,1)
dL_dphiDot = L.diff( phiDot , 1 )
dL_dphix = L.diff( phix , 1 )
euler_lagrange_eq =- dL_dphiDot.diff(t,1) - dL_dphix.diff(x,1) + L.diff(phi)
pde = sp.Eq(euler_lagrange_eq, 0)


lbda_to_zero = euler_lagrange_eq.subs(lbda, 0)



# operator method and fourier method



operatorEquation = sp.Eq(dalembertian_symbol - m**2, 1)

#Take fourier tranform on both sides

fourierTransformedOperatorEquation = str(integral_symbol)+ '1/'+str(math.pi**2) +'*'+ str((dalembertian_symbol - m**2) *D_k)+'*' + str( sp.exp(sp.I *k*x))+ '=' + str(integral_symbol)+'1/'+str(math.pi**2)  + str(kronecker_delta_symbol)+'(x)'
fourierTransformedOperatorEquationCompled = str(integral_symbol)+'1/'+str(math.pi**2)+'*'  + str((k**2 - m**2) *D_k)+'*' + str( sp.exp(sp.I *k*x))+ '=' + str(integral_symbol)+'1/'+str(math.pi**2)+'*'  + str(kronecker_delta_symbol)+'(x)'

#Read off D_k

read_Off_D_k =  1/ (math.sqrt(math.pi))**2  * 1/(-k**2 + m**2)
fourier_transformed_read_Off_D_k = str(integral_symbol)+ 'dk'+str(1/math.pi**2)+ '*'+ str( sp.exp(- sp.I *k*x)) + str(1/ (math.sqrt(math.pi))**2  * 1/(-k**2 + m**2))
D_x = fourier_transformed_read_Off_D_k
print(D_x)
```

So far, this code outputs the correct Euler-Lagrange equation/pde.

I have now used the operator method to get the case of lambda going to zero.

I am now turning on interactions, to compute the interaction theory.

**My goals**

- Implement the propagator symbolically
- Implement renormalization by counter terms see for example [this](http://fma.if.usp.br/%7Eburdman/QFT1/lecture_21.pdf)
- Implement [callan-symanzik equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callan%E2%80%93Symanzik_equation) in python for $\phi^4$. See for example [this exceptional lecture](https://youtu.be/tHeHT8Nrjss?t=849)

**Question -broken down into parts**

How do I modify this Python code to calculate the free propagator/ green's function symbolically without the interaction i.e. when the interaction is turned off or lambda is set to zero?

To solve this I am hoping to implement this by  Fourier transform/ operator method. This can be done by noticing that rewriting the Euler Lagrange equation with $\phi(x,t)$ replaced with the free propagator symbol $D(x,t)$, and then taking the Fourier transform of both sides. Here the equation in question is the Euler Lagrange equation except we have rearranged such that one side is set to  0, but instead of zero we replace the 0 with a delta function and consider the case where it is one.

sticking to the case of 2 d i.e x and t are the only variables

Mathematically it is something like so:

$(\Box  + m^2 ) \phi(x,t) = \delta(x)$

$\int \frac{dk}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} ^2 (\Box + m^2) \phi(x,t) e^{ikx} = \int{dk}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}^2 \delta(x) e^{ikx}$

$\int \frac{dk}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} ^2 (-k^2 + m^2) \phi(x,t) e^{ikx} = \int{dk}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}^2 $

We can then read off $\phi (k)  = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{-k^2 + m^2}$

$\phi (x) = \int \frac{dk}{2 \pi} \frac{e^{- ikx}}{-k^2 + m^2}$

Let this $\phi(x)$ be $D(x)$ the free propagator

With the interaction the goal is to solve something like:

$(\Box  + m^2 ) \phi(x,t) = \lambda \phi(x,t)^3$

Please see [section 4](https://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Ehelling/classical_fields.pdf) of this resource on how this is carried out.

How is this implemented symbolically in Python code? My feeling is that it might even involve graphs.

How do we implement counter-term renormalization for $\phi^4$ theory symbolically in Python code?

What is the easiest implementation (symbolically) of callan-symanzik equation for the $\phi^4$ theory in Python code?

Basically, we need to add a few functions to the code.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question mark. Perhaps you can revise to make it clearer what you're asking?

Comment: @Richard thank you for the feedback. I have now made a first attempt at adding a question broken down into parts below the "My goals" section of the post. The section I added is called "Question -broken down into parts". I have also revised other parts of the post adding more context a reference and some mathematics.